# Visual Studio 2012 Memory Spike and Hanging

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Recently, Visual Studio 2012 has been acting up.  As I'm developing ASP .NET applications I routinely tab between the browser (Chrome) and the Visual Studio IDE. Sometimes when I attempt to tab back into Visual Studio the window will not come up.  At that time if I look at my task manager I'll see that the `devenv.exe` process is using about 10 to 20% of CPU time and is gathering more and more memory for itself. This goes on for about 20 seconds or so before the IDE is responsive and usable again. Eventually, the IDE can't recover and I need to terminate the process.

My desktop is a 64-bit quad-core i7 @ 3.4GHz with 8 GB of RAM, running Windows 7 OS. Typically `devenv.exe` will use about 500 MB of RAM. When the problem above begins to happen it will quicky ramp up to 1.5 GB and has been as high as 2 GB.

The only add-on I'm using is ReSharper 7.1. I have no further IDE customizations apart from the built-in dark color scheme.

**EDIT** — I have tried disabling and removing R# which has had no effect on this problem.

**EDIT** — [Bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781936/visual-studio-2012-memory-spike-and-hanging) on Microsoft Connect

Comment: I occasionally see VS2012 freeze for up to 45 seconds, though I have not checked memory consumption.  This usually happens when I switch to a new source branch, causing around 8 projects to be reloaded.  You way want to report this issue on http://connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: @EricJ. Good suggestion; I've linked the related Connect bug report.

Comment: I had similar on Win 7 32-bit but after migrating to 64-bit Win 8 with my development environment and OS installed on an SSD, problem gone. It does suggest memory usage/paging is part of the problem.

Comment: @roger_rowland I am using SSD. It is relatively small, but still has 16.4 GB of 119 GB free. The page file is pre-allocated at 8 GB.

Comment: I'm using 64-bit Win 8 with a SSD for the OS and VS2012 and a fast RAID 10 with high end caching controller for source files.  Still see hangs.

Comment: If you have installed any plugins such as Visual Assist, it will take away a good amount of memory in the name of devenv.exe. When you tab back into Visual Studio, its ongoing background operation can cause significant CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this all the time until I installed VS 2012 update 4 then it all went away.
I also only use resharper ( version 8).